# Does Django query the database on every iteration?

Tags: python, django

In Django, if I write:

```
for i in User.objects.all():
    i.active()
```

I know I can set a variable to the current state of User.objects.all() and then run the loop but I'd like to know what python is really doing. Will Python get the list of users only once and then iterate over that list? Or will it query the database on every iteration?

Comment: If you're asking whether `User.objects.all()` is evaluated only once for the whole loop or once per iteration, the answer is "only once for the whole loop".

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Comment: @BrenBarn do you have any evidence to support it?

Comment: I recommend you use [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). That way you can always see what queries are being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

> The expression list is evaluated once

This part of it doesn't have anything to with Django.  In a statement like `for x in blah`, `blah` is only evaluated once, at the beginning of the loop.  (In theory, it could be possible for the object do to other expensive stuff on every iteration, but as the references in aus_lacy's answer show, Django doesn't do this.)

Answer (score 1):

When you query the database with `.all()` you are querying one time and creating a `QuerySet` object. You can then do whatever it is you want with that `QuerySet` For more information see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.all) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/).